# minikube v1.28.0 unable to ping host.minikube.internal windows 10

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have started minikube with `minikube start --driver=hyperv` on windows 10, this is the second laptop i try with, the other laptop has window 11 by the way, but I am always not able to ping `host.minikube.internal` checked also [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/host-access/)

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> minikube version
minikube version: v1.28.0
commit: 986b1ebd987211ed16f8cc10aed7d2c42fc8392f
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> minikube ssh
                         _             _
            _         _ ( )           ( )
  ___ ___  (_)  ___  (_)| |/')  _   _ | |_      __
/' _ ` _ `\| |/' _ `\| || , <  ( ) ( )| '_`\  /'__`\
| ( ) ( ) || || ( ) || || |\`\ | (_) || |_) )(  ___/
(_) (_) (_)(_)(_) (_)(_)(_) (_)`\___/'(_,__/'`\____)

$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       minikube
172.24.48.1     host.minikube.internal
172.24.58.100   control-plane.minikube.internal
$ ping host.minikube.internal
PING host.minikube.internal (172.24.48.1): 56 data bytes
```

I have to deploy a cron job on kubernetes that calls an API on my localhost.
Someone knows why I'm not able to ping `host.minikube.internal`?
Or should I deploy the API and the cronjob on kubernetes avoiding calling localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the windows firewall, you have to deactivate the public network settings
[image]